# how can i make a threadsafe progress bar in C#? what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hey everyone, can someone let me know what they see wrong with this code ?

it throws "Cross-thread operation not valid" exception, on

```
_DialogueThread.Start();
```

but if i remove "owner" from

```
_progressDialogue = new Progresser{Owner = _owner, StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent};
```

the exception wont be thrown but the progressDialouge will be shown then hidden right away .

now i understand why this the error is thrown if i set the progressDialouge.Owner to a parent form that was created on a different thread. but why dose the form disappears when i dont ?  what am i doing wrong ?

thanks

```
class Sampleer : BackgroundWorker
{
    private Progresser _progressDialogue;
    private Thread _DialogueThread;
    private Form _owner;
    private bool _SampleSuccess;

    public Sampleer(Form owner)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        _progressDialogue = new Progresser{Owner = _owner, StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent};
        _progressDialogue.Closed += ProgressDialogueClosed;
        WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        DoWork += Sampleer_DoWork;
        RunWorkerCompleted += Sampleer_RunWorkerCompleted;
        ProgressChanged += Sampleer_ProgressChanged;
    }

    private void Sampleer_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

       //UPDATE STATUS CODE IS HERE

    }

    void ProgressDialogueClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CancelAsync();
        Dispose();
    }

    void Sampleer_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //FINISH PROCESS
    }


    void Sampleer_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        _DialogueThread = new Thread(_progressDialogue.Show);
        _DialogueThread.Start();


        //DO LONG PROCESS HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you inheriting from BackgroundWorker in this case?

Comment: I am making a SampleerBackgroundWorker that pops out a new form with progress bar while its working

Comment: You create a backgroundworker to offload work from the main ui thread. You should not be creating ui elements in this non-ui thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes decyclone is right, there are many mistakes in the code and in your approach to solution.

You are inherting BackgroundWorker type but subscribing to its own events?
Instead override the methods that are responsible for raising the event in your class.
ex: Instead of subscribing to DoWork, override OnDoWork method.

I've created a sample application, in which a Form (when performing a background task) shows  another Form (BackgroundWorkUINotification) and starts the background task in BackgroundWorker thread. The BackgroundWorkUINotification notifies the main form when the Form's CancelButton is clicked.

The main Form when notified, closes the notifier and cancels the background task.

**Code below: BackgroundWorkUINotification  Form**

```
public partial class BackgroundWorkUINotification : Form
    {
        public event EventHandler CancelClicked;

    public BackgroundWorkUINotification()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // call code to animate progress bar..
        // probably in another BackgroundWorker that reports progress..            

        this.cancelButton.Click += HandleCancelButtonOnClick;
    }


    protected virtual void OnCancelClicked()
    {
        if (CancelClicked != null)
            this.CancelClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void HandleCancelButtonOnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.OnCancelClicked();
    }
}
```

**Main Form**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        this.backgroundWorker.DoWork += HandleBackgroundWorkerOnDoWork;
        this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += HandleBackgroundWorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted;
        this.backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    private void HandleDataRequest()
    {
        // show UI notification...
        BackgroundWorkUINotification backgroundWorkUINotification = new BackgroundWorkUINotification();
        backgroundWorkUINotification.CancelClicked += HandleBackgroundWorkUINotificationOnCancelClicked;
        backgroundWorkUINotification.Show(this);

        // start the background worker 
        this.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void HandleBackgroundWorkUINotificationOnCancelClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // UI notification Form, Cancelled
        // close the form...
        BackgroundWorkUINotification backgroundWorkUINotification = (BackgroundWorkUINotification)sender;
        backgroundWorkUINotification.Close();

        // stop the background worker thread...
        if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void HandleBackgroundWorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void HandleBackgroundWorkerOnDoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // do some work here..
        // also check for CancellationPending property on BackgroundWorker
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your action (button click), i would create the progress dialog, and then fire off the background worker. The background worker then reports back to the dialog in the ProgressChanged event.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    private void btnDoSomething_Click(object sender0, RoutedEventArgs e0) {

        _progressDialogue = new Progresser{Owner = _owner, StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent};
        _progressDialogue.Closed += ProgressDialogueClosed;
        _progressDialogue.Show();

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            DoSomething();

            e.Result = result;
        };
        worker.ProgressChanged += delegate(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
            progressDialogue.Update()
        };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
            progressDialogue.Close()
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(new CustomArgs() {
            SomeValue = txtValue.Text,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes in your approach. Let me point them out one by one.

- You inherit `BackgroundWorker`. That is fine. But you create another thread inside (`_DialogueThread`). There is no need. `DoWork()` method runs in a separate thread.
- You create/use/manipulate a `UI` element in another thread. Now, always remember. A `Thread` never creates a `UI` element. Its the other way around. A `UI` element creates a `Thread`. `Progresser` in your case should be creating a new `Thread` or using `BackgroundWorker` to do any background work you require.

`

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago I had the same trouble.
This was helped me: ["MSDN. How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
I used first aproach (checking InvokeRequired) because it is easiest way.

Hope it is helpful advise!

Comment: I think that "InvokeRequired" aprach is more easiest than "BackgroundWorker" :)